# httpclient.execute works but overloaded function throws exception

Tags: java, android, httpresponse

I'm writing an Android application. It sends a HTTPPost to a server and receives the answer, when I use :

`public final HttpResponse execute (HttpUriRequest request)`

it's ok,

but when I try to use:

`public T execute (HttpUriRequest request, ResponseHandler<? extends T> responseHandler)`

it throws `ClientProtocolException`

because of some reasons I wanna use the second function, what should I do? What is the exception for ?

here is the code that uses the first function :

```
  HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://foo.Com/GeneralControls/Service.asmx/Login");
  DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
  HttpResponse response =  httpclient.execute(httppost) ;
```

and here is the code that uses the second function:

```
   HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://foo.Com/GeneralControls/Service.asmx/Login");
   DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
   ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler=new BasicResponseHandler();
   String response = httpclient.execute(httppost , responseHandler) ;
```

throws ClientProtocolException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a protocol problem, the webservice was changing the Destination URL and it produced an Exception

Answer (score 0):

See the below code is working fine for me

```
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE,
                Util.cookieStore);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost,
                    localContext);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But you are trying to pass ResponseHandler and it accepts httpContext